# Rails 3 uninitialized constant ... (NameError) in custom initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initializer, contact-form, nameerror, uninitialized-constant

I'm trying to implement the contact form described [here](http://www.bentonporter.com/2011/01/how-to-create-a-contact-form-in-rails).

I get the following error when I run rails server:

```
/home/user/project/web/config/initializers/app_config.rb:11:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant RailsContactForm (NameError)
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:200:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:200:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
from /home/user/project/web/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/project/web/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
from /home/user/project/web/config.ru:1:in `new'
from /home/user/project/web/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `eval'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `parse_file'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:162:in `app'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:253:in `wrapped_app'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:204:in `start'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
/home/user/project/web/config/initializers/app_config.rb:11:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant RailsContactForm (NameError)
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:200:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:200:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
from /home/user/project/web/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/project/web/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
from /home/user/project/web/config.ru:1:in `new'
from /home/user/project/web/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `eval'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `parse_file'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:162:in `app'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:253:in `wrapped_app'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:204:in `start'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I can see he hasn't defined RailsContactForm anywhere else. I don't know enough rails to know whether this is intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that tutorial `RailsContactForm` is the name of the main app.

You'll need to change that to your app's name.

Answer (score 2):

In this line: "RailsContactForm::Application.configure"

RailsContactForm is just the name he gave the application when he ran rails create. Just substitute that with your application name.

Comment: Thanks also. Not much to choose between answers. I'll give you some rep when they let me.